# How can I format date_space_hour to a time format

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I get this **text** data in an excel worksheet

```
16/10/2018 00:11:53
16/10/2018 00:41:52
16/10/2018 04:21:19
16/10/2018 04:30:37
```

it is "day/month/year **space** hour:minute:second"

I tried formatting as date or time but nothing happens (it shoud be converted to a floating point number representing date and time)

I need to extract the day and the hour (h:m:s) with excel functions

I cannot use the "convert text to columns" excel feature to separate the date and hour at the space, because it would create/overwrite neighbor colums, and I cannot move/overwrite the data columns (I'm not the only user of the worksheet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way:

[copy 1 from any cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84k7h.png)

multiply all values by 1 (copy 1 from any cell, paste special, choose "values" and "multiply")
The dates will be turned into a floating number

[Paste special](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LERgY.png)

Then format the data as "personalized format",

```
d/m/yyyy hh:mm:ss
```

then extract the hour with

```
=TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1), SECOND(A1))
```

In spanish version:

```
=NSHORA(HORA(A1);MINUTO(A1);SEGUNDO(A1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula (basically `LEFT()` and `MID()`):

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH("/",A1)-1)&MID(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1),LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ",A1)+1)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, but if I write the text I posted, excel automatically interprets it as a time format (and ifI reformat the number type to "general", it is shown as a floating point number). There is any way to tell excell that such text should be interpreted as date-hour format?

Comment: @hokisajam - What do you mean? I have the data formatted as "Time". I can still use that formula, and the result is even set to "Time" in Excel, but looks fine.

Comment: here is the spanish version: =EXTRAE(A1;HALLAR(" ";A1);LARGO(A1)-HALLAR(" ";A1)+1)

Comment: Actually, there is a bug which includes the space. Here is corrected =EXTRAE(A1;HALLAR(" ";A1)+1;LARGO(A1)-HALLAR(" ";A1)+1)

Comment: The result still remains as text. It can be converted to time by multipliying by 1: =1*(EXTRAE(A4;HALLAR(" ";A4)+1;LARGO(A4)-HALLAR(" ";A4)+1))